# How to animate offset in HorizontalPager?

Tags: animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have three cards in HorizontalPager and I want to animate its offset [like this one](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1588664/screenshots/8257559/media/d94b36cb7822008df8055c90ca6e2238.mp4) when user scroll through pages.

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = 3)
val currentIndex = pagerState.currentPage
HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) { page ->
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.7f)
                .padding(22.dp)
                .offset(y = if (currentIndex == page) 0.dp else 70.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
            elevation = 110.dp
        ) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the offset using `pagerState.currentPageOffset`.

When you scroll the `HorizontalPager`, the `currentPage` will not change until you release the drag. When you scroll to the right, `currentPageOffset` increases from `0f` to `1f`, and when you scroll to the left, it decreases from `0f` to `-1f`.

In my code, I calculate `offset` for each page:

1. The offset of the current page should increase as we scroll left and right, so we can take `absoluteValue`.
2. The left page offset should decrease as long as `currentPageOffset` changes from `0f` to `-1f`.
3. The right page offset should decrease while `currentPageOffset` increases from `0f` to `1f`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = 3)
    val currentIndex = pagerState.currentPage
    val currentPageOffset = pagerState.currentPageOffset
    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) { page ->
        val offset = maxOffset * when (page) {
            currentIndex -> {
                currentPageOffset.absoluteValue
            }
            currentIndex - 1 -> {
                1 + currentPageOffset.coerceAtMost(0f)
            }
            currentIndex + 1 -> {
                1 - currentPageOffset.coerceAtLeast(0f)
            }
            else -> {
                1f
            }
        }
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                .fillMaxHeight(0.7f)
                .padding(22.dp)
                .offset(y = offset),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
            elevation = 110.dp
        ) {}
    }
}

private val maxOffset = 70.dp
```

Result:

[image]